# Embeddable and ElementCollection nesting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, embeddable

I have fairly typical scenario where there is a main @Entity and everything inside him is embeddable (so everything inside doesn't make sense without the parent). Now JPA 2.0 is blocking me to nest a @ElementCollection inside a @Embeddable defined in another @ElementCollection:

> JSR-317
>   2.6 Collections of Embeddable Classes and Basic Types
>   An embeddable class (including an embeddable class within another embeddable class) that is contained within an element collection must not contain an element collection, nor may it contain a relationship to an entity other than a many-to-one or one-to-one relationship

Now the question is: why is this? A simple example:

```
@Entity
public class Tournament {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable
    private List<Edition>;
}

@Embeddable
public class Edition {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable
    private List<Round>
}

@Embeddable
public class Round {

    blabla;
}
```

What's the problem having this? This is just an example, you could define Round and Edition as Entity and solve the problem, but in my case for a number of reasons I need to enforce that something very nested doesn't make sense without his parent.

Why JPA 2.0 has to stop me doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your situation violates the specification element you pasted in:

Edition is itself @Embeddable, and contains an element collection of Round, and thus:

An embeddable class (Edition) that is contained within an element collection (Tournament.editions) must not contain an element collection (Edition.rounds).

As to why you can't do this - if you look at the examples from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection then you'll see that the child (Edition) would be mapped with only a FK back to the owner (Tournament.id) without an ID column of its own - on the grounds that as a Weak entity, it has no ID of its own, and is only defined by reference to the ID of the Tournament.

Taking the Round, if that too is a weak entity, then it should be defined by FK reference to the Edition - but we already said that has no ID of its own, so you can't map this in the DB without adding an ID to the Edition - at which point it would be an entity in its own right, and not be simply @Embeddable.

Looking at the Wikipedia example from the comment below - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity - the examples of weak entities there are OrderNumber, CustomerNumber etc - things which only ever make any sense when embedded in another object.

You can still have entities which have parent mappings (i.e. a Tournament reference on the Edition) and/or bi-directional references. You can force the parent to be defined on the Edition with a nullable=false attribute on the @ManyToOne annotation, and thus enforce the requirements of your model.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, it is needed by the model: it shouldn't be possible to load an Edition without his Tournament, and an Edition cannot exists if you don't have a Tournament first. It's the notion of [Weak Entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) that is well known in ER diagrams but seems to be not well implemented in JPA.
I was just trying to understand why in JPA you cannot have more nested embeddable elementcollections (maybe there is an implementation problem?), that is a common way of describing things in the real world.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. At the end I realised Embeddable does not map exactly with the idea of weak entity. A weak entity should have a composite primary key composed by the foreign key to the parent entity + his own id, and this is not the case for a Embeddable object.
So I think the last option you gave is the most reasonable, even though I thought there was something more direct to map a weak entity, but I was wrong.