# Can I use @ElementCollection inside an @Embedded?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with an optional sub-entity containing more fields. The sub-entity again has a collection of elements.

Is this generally impossible with Hibernate or am I missing something?

```
@Entity @Table(name="my_entity")
public class MyEntity {
  @Id 
  private Long id;

  @Embedded 
  @JoinTable(name="..." joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="myEntityId"))
  private OptionalFields optionalFields;
}

@Embeddable
public class OptionalFields {
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="...", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="myEntityId"))
   private List<OpeningHoursItem> openingHours;
}

@Embeddable
public class OpeningHoursItem {

}
```

Error message is:

```
Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: my_entity, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(opening_hours)]
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126397/embeddable-and-elementcollection-nesting) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @Jan, interesting link. It is similar but not quite the same, since I have cardinality 1:1:N whereas your link has 1:M:N.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. If I only add any field to OpeningHoursItem and replace name='...' with proper names - it works.

Comment: @wypieprz O RLY??? WTF. What version of Hibernate are you using? Mine is 4.3.6.Final

Comment: 4.3.5.Final (hibernate-core + hibernate-entitymanager + hibernate-jpamodelgen + hibernate-c3p0) and 5.1.0.Final (hibernate-validator)

Comment: Maybe I stripped down the sample code too much. No idea. Or maybe it's time for vacation?

Comment: When I place the ElementCollection and CollectionTable annotations on the getter, it works. On the field it doesn't. TIME FOR VACATION!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may sound strange, but it really works:

Move all your annotations from the fields to the getters, then the error goes away.